# How to leave out a part of programming code, in a programming code quote?

Tags: quotes, lean

How to leave out a part of programming code, in a programming code quote?

In particular I have the following code snippet (from the Lean proof assistant):

```
def single (a : α) (b : β) : α →₀ β :=
⟨λa', if a = a' then b else 0,
  finite_subset (@finite_singleton α a) $ assume a', by by_cases h : a = a'; 
  simp [h]⟩
```

And I want to leave out a part, like:

```
def single (a : α) (b : β) : α →₀ β :=
⟨λa', if a = a' then b else 0,
  [...]⟩
```

For text quotes I know that we can use the [...] for leaving out part of the quote.

But what do we use in the case of programming code quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lean has `sorry`, which is even syntactically-valid if the omitted part is an expression, as it is here. So if you are writing an exercise in Lean and you want provide a partially-filled answer that the reader could try to fill in:

```
def single (a : α) (b : β) : α →₀ β :=
⟨λa', if a = a' then b else 0,
  sorry⟩
```

It differs from `_` in that Lean will not try to fill in the blank when you use `sorry`.